# WinEdt autocompletion

Tags: winedt, auto-completion

How to use autocomplete feature in WinEdt?

It's very hard to use `\ref{}` and similar functions without autocomplete. I tried <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl+Space</kbd> but in vain.

Comment: Just to clarify, do you mean autocompletion of `\label`s?

Comment: yes auto completion for labels and references.

Comment: after you type the closing `}` in `\ref{}`, WinEdt should bring up a list of the labels present in the current document. No other keys are required, unless something's wrong with your configuration or document.

Comment: yes it was working like that, but now something wrong happened, i don't know what.

Comment: You have probably modified something in WinEdt settings, otherwise it should work. Try to run `Rebuild All` from `Options -> Maintenance` menu to rebuild the settings.

Comment: @karlkoeller: nothing changed.

Comment: Just another question. In the Tree, can you see the branch Bibliography with the indication of the number of bibitems?

Comment: @JosephWright; Why would he? It doesn't answer the question. It simply states how it should work. The problem case here is that it doesn't anymore, which can be solved as I explained below.

Comment: @Mythio There are cases in which your answer doesn't work...

Comment: @Misaki Can you please tell us if you still have this problem?

Comment: @karlkoeller; perhaps, but then the other "solution" definitely doesn't work either, so it makes little difference to my point..

Comment: @Mythio You are right about this. The other one is definitely not a solution.

Answer (score 2):

After you type the closing `}` in `\ref{},` WinEdt should bring up a list of the labels present in the current document, or, more precisely, in the current *main file*. No other keys are required, unless something's wrong with your configuration or document.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Clicking on the Icon "Build Tree" should help. It is available by clicking the "Tree..."-Button in the tool bar.

Comment: I think "tree" build the directory and its content, not to solve my auto-complete issue.

Comment: It seems that you haven't solved yet. Just to know: when you look at the Tree, is your bibliography marked with a question mark?

Comment: no, it's normal

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem before myself. Two things can be done to remedy this issue.

1. Build the tree for the document, as suggested before.

   (didn't work for your particular case)
2. Set the main file of your document.

   If you are working in only one file, just set that one as main.

   You can do this by going to Project -> Set Main File.

After that, autocompletion should work as before.

Comment: This really needs to be said.  Autocomplete, as far as i can see, is not meant to work for anything except the main file of a project.  And it will not register any bib file you are using until you use build tree.